# storing a unique value with Top is not posible Sybase

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

I wonder why i can not do that in sybase 15.5
My table is call "web_titles"

title_id is a varchar(6)

```
declare @idAux varchar(6)
set @idAux  = (select top 1 title_id from web_titles)
```

if i just do

```
select top 1 title_id from web_titles
```

return

```
title_id
-----------
PC8888
```

but if i try to set the variable i recive

Sybase error

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top' "

I dont understand why. Any idee?

Comment: @lad2025 Worked 100000000000000000000000 thanks !! really i was stucked for a long !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign value to variable you could use:

```
declare @idAux varchar(6);
select top 1 @idAux = title_id from web_titles;
```

Keep in mind that `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

TOP, ORDER BY and UNION are not allowed in subqueries in ASE